# Java read email from gmail behind a proxy server

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am developing a program which reads email from gmail, in an organization which has a proxy system to monitor user activity. I have tried using all possible solutions, but none seem to work. Any help would be really appreciated.Thanks in advance for your help.

Code :

```
 public MailReader()
 {
 /*  Set the mail properties  */
 Properties props = System.getProperties();
 props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
 try
 {
 /*  Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */
 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
 Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
 store.connect("imap.gmail.com","<EMAIL>", "<PASS>");

 /*  Mention the folder name which you want to read. */
 inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
 System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());

 /*Open the inbox using store.*/
 inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

 /*  Get the messages which is unread in the Inbox*/
 Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));

 /* Use a suitable FetchProfile    */
 FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
 fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
 fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
 inbox.fetch(messages, fp);

 try
 {
 printAllMessages(messages);
 inbox.close(true);
 store.close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 System.out.println("Exception arise at the time of read mail");
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 catch (NoSuchProviderException e)
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 System.exit(1);
 }
 catch (MessagingException e)
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 System.exit(2);
 }
 }
```

The flowing is the error code that I get. `java.net.UnknownHostException`

```
    javax.mail.MessagingException: imap.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: imap.gmail.com
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javaapplication1.MailReader.<init>(MailReader.java:29)
    at javaapplication1.MailReader.main(MailReader.java:149)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: imap.gmail.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:113)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:110)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:632)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: show us the code please

Comment: Dear @SLaks I get java.net.UnknownHostException . ie. The java can't communicate with the gmail server.

Comment: Ultimately your DNS server doesn't know or won't give you information about imap.gmail.com.  This means you'll never connect because it can't find the IP address you need.  In your environment you're unlikely to be able to solve this because of the DNS issue.

Comment: @stdunbar The how can my browser and widows mail can connect to gmail through the same proxy system?

Comment: My guess is that there is some configuration on your local machine that allows it to resolve and go through the proxy.  Try to connect to 74.125.69.108 or 74.125.69.109 as that is what imap.gmail.com resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

[Here oracle say:](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.htm#proxy)

> JavaMail does not currently support accessing mail servers through a web proxy server.
> ...
> If your proxy server supports the SOCKS V4 or V5 protocol (http://www.socks.nec.com/aboutsocks.html, RFC1928) and allows anonymous connections, and you're using JDK 1.5 or newer and JavaMail 1.4.5 or newer, you can configure a SOCKS proxy on a per-session, per-protocol basis by setting the "mail.smtp.socks.host" property as described in the javadocs for the com.sun.mail.smtp package. Similar properties exist for the "imap" and "pop3" protocols.